# How do I create a parent-child relationship in immutable Kotlin classes

Tags: kotlin

I have immutable classes representing a tree, where the children need a parent reference.

```
sealed class Node {
    abstract val parent: Parent?
}

class Child(
    override val parent: Parent,
) : Node()

class Parent(
    override val parent: Parent?,
    val children: List<Node>
) : Node()
```

Is there an idiomatic Kotlin way of creating a parent with a list of children that have the parent reference set correctly?

Comment: If you want to keep immutability but you can't provide the parent when creating a child I guess the only option would be using reflection to change the children's `parent` backing field, otherwise the trivial answer would be to make `parent` mutable or to provide a parent to each child (but I guess that's not what you want)

Comment: I'm not sure that reflectively changing fields meets the criteria of immutable ;-)

Comment: Well, I can't disagree with you :-D

Answer (score 3):

You could try with a root node and builder params:

```
sealed class Node {
    data class Root(
        val createChildren: ParentList.() -> Unit
    ) : Node() {
        val children: List<Node> = ParentList(this).apply(createChildren)
    }

    data class Branch(
        val createChildren: ParentList.() -> Unit,
        val parent: Node
    ) : Node() {
        val children: List<Node> = ParentList(this).apply(createChildren)
    }

    data class Leaf(
        val parent: Node
    ) : Node()
}

class ParentList(
    val parent: Node,
    private val children: MutableList<Node> = mutableListOf()
) : List<Node> by children {

    fun branch(createChildren: ParentList.() -> Unit) {
        children += Node.Branch(createChildren, parent)
    }

    fun leaf() {
        children += Node.Leaf(parent)
    }

}

fun root(createChildren: ParentList.() -> Unit) = Node.Root(createChildren)
```

They can be constructed like the following (probably would want to add extra details to either of the nodes):

```
fun usage() {

    val graph = root {
        branch {
            leaf()
        }
        branch {
            branch {
                leaf()
            }
            leaf()
        }
    }
}
```

You can allow access to potential children and/or parents with extension properties:

```
val Node.children: List<Node> get() = when(this) {
    is Node.Root -> children
    is Node.Branch -> children
    is Node.Leaf -> emptyList()
}

val Node.parent: Node? get() = when(this) {
    is Node.Root -> null
    is Node.Branch -> parent
    is Node.Leaf -> parent
}
```

So you can navigate the descendants:

```
fun Node.allChildren(): List<Node> = 
  children + children.flatMap { it.allChildren() }
```

Or navigate up:

```
fun Node.allParents(): List<Node> = 
  listOfNotNull(parent).flatMap { listOf(it) + allParents() }
```

To avoid evaluation if doing a search that may finish early you can always use sequences instead of lists:

```
fun Node.allChildren(): Sequence<Node> = 
  children.asSequence() + children.asSequence().flatMap { it.allChildren() }

fun Node.allParents(): Sequence<Node> = 
  listOfNotNull(parent).asSequence().flatMap { sequenceOf(it) + it.allParents() }
```

**Note:** watch out for Stackoverflows

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach could be to make the `parent` settable from within `Node` and provide it with a list of children to set the parent for.

```
sealed class Node(
    children: List<Node> = listOf()
) {
    var parent: Container? = null
        private set

    init {
        (this as? Container)?.apply {
            children.forEach { it.parent = this }            
        }
    }
}

data class Child(val type: String) : Node()

data class Container(
    val children: List<Node>
) : Node(children)
```

The only side-effect is, that `parent` won't be used by the data classes as property.

Comment: I've relaxed the data class requirement, as the copy methods would let clients replace the children with the wrong ones. Having a var with a private setter is cunning

Answer (score 1):

Instead of insisting on immutability then maybe you settle on read only. Think of it as analogous to kotlins `MutableList` / `List`. Something like this:

```
sealed class Node {
    abstract val parent: Container?
}

abstract class Child : Node()

abstract class Container : Node() {
    abstract val children: List<Node>
}

private class MutableChild(override var parent: Container?) : Child()

private class MutableContainer(override var parent: Container?, override var children: List<Node>) : Container()

fun buildTree() : Node {
    val children = mutableListOf<Node>()
    val parent = MutableContainer(null, children)
    MutableChild(parent).also { children.add(it) }
    MutableChild(parent).also { children.add(it) }

    return parent
}
```

Comment: Ah, instead of having MutableChild and MutableContainer, we can just initialise the parent with a list that we then immediately mutate - see my answer

Answer (score 1):

We can lazily evaluate a list of builders the first time that the children are needed. Note that this is safe only where the rest of the codebase is sufficiently  referentially transparent.

```
sealed class Node {
    abstract val parent: Parent?
}

class Child(
    override val parent: Parent
) : Node()

class Parent(
    override val parent: Parent?,
    private val childBuilders: List<(Parent) -> Node>
) : Node() {

    val children: List<Node> by lazy {
        childBuilders.map { it(this)}
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

We can populate the Parent with a mutable list that we fill when we have the reference.

```
sealed class Node {
    abstract val parent: Parent?
}

class Child(
    override val parent: Parent
) : Node()

class Parent(
    override val parent: Parent?,
    val children: List<Node>
) : Node() {
    companion object {
        operator fun invoke(parent: Parent?, childBuilders: List<(Parent) -> Node>): Parent {
            val children = mutableListOf<Node>()
            return Parent(parent, children).apply {
                children.addAll(childBuilders.map { it(this) })
            }
        }
    }
}
```